# How can I improve the query in terms of performance?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a function that first extracts all the directories found and sorts in alphabetical order, and then extracts all the other data that are not directories and also sorts in alphabetical order and finally combines them.

```
 @Get('roots')
  async findRoots(@Req() request: Request) {
    const user = await this.authService.findCurrentUser(request);
    const directories = await this.fileService.findAll({
      relations: ['user', 'parent', 'parent.parent'],
      order: {
        name: 'ASC',
      },
      where: {
        user: user.user_id,
        parent: IsNull(),
        type: 'dir',
      },
    });
    const otherFiles = await this.fileService.findAll({
      relations: ['user', 'parent', 'parent.parent'],
      order: {
        name: 'ASC',
      },
      where: {
        user: user.user_id,
        parent: IsNull(),
        type: Not('dir'),
      },
    });
    return directories.concat(otherFiles);
  }
```

But I don't like the fact that I have to perform two queries. Is it possible to implement this somehow with a single request?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove `type` from your WHERE condition.

```
@Get('roots')
  async findRoots(@Req() request: Request) {
    const user = await this.authService.findCurrentUser(request);
    const directoriesAndFiles = await this.fileService.findAll({
      relations: ['user', 'parent', 'parent.parent'],
      order: {
        name: 'ASC',
      },
      where: {
        user: user.user_id,
        parent: IsNull(),
      },
    });
    return directoriesAndFiles;
  }
```

If you want directories before files, I suggest you do the separation inside your code without making two queries.

```
@Get('roots')
  async findRoots(@Req() request: Request) {
    const user = await this.authService.findCurrentUser(request);
    const directoriesAndFiles = await this.fileService.findAll({
      relations: ['user', 'parent', 'parent.parent'],
      order: {
        name: 'ASC',
      },
      where: {
        user: user.user_id,
        parent: IsNull(),
      },
    });
    
    const directories = [];
    const otherFiles = [];

    for (const directoryOrFile of directoriesAndFiles) {
      if (directoryOrFile.type === 'dir') {
        directories.push(directoryOrFile);
      } else {
        otherFiles.push(directoryOrFile);
      }
    }

    return directories.concat(otherFiles);
  }
```